# Azure Devops and release of multiple repositories

Tags: git, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm, gitversion

I have multiple repositories which contain microservices. What I want to do is that when I release a new version I want to deploy the whole system. Each repo generates a docker image and deployments are done using a helm chart. Is there some neat way of doing it ? currently I need to release a specific version (I am using Gitversion in ContinuousDeployment mode) of all the repos and then use a release pipeline for deployment. Is there some good practice for this that I've missed ?

Cheers !

Comment: The good practice here is to make each application independent for real. If they are splitted in repos but cannot be deployed individually, the problem is the fact of they are too coupled to each other. It's a distributed monolith.

Comment: You can do some tricks to handle that, but it may lead you to a dependency hell sooner or later.

Comment: Create one build pipleine that builds all repo's and creates build artifacts. These artifacts will be tagged with a single build number. The release pipeline picks up artifacts from a specific build and releases it.

Comment: We've built a tooling for that - while this example shows how to do it for monorepo, same can be done for multi-repo or a mixed-repo - essentially it auto-versions and auto-bundles components components to give you single version. And it's using simple individual pipelines rather than one huge one - https://worklifenotes.com/2023/05/12/how-to-promote-software-to-production-with-reliza-hub/